# Gatsbyjs & localStorage: Persisting state

Tags: javascript, local-storage, gatsby, react-context

I'm building a GDPR banner for my site. I want this banner to appear on every page of my site until the user clicks the accept button. In my Gatsby site I am using the **Context API** to store whether the user has accepted the terms with a piece of state in local storage called GDPR_Accepted. I initialize it to false and when the user clicks the accept button in the GDPR banner I toggled it to true. After it is set to true the GDPR banner should not be shown on any page.

I have this functionality working, except when the user leaves my site and comes back GDPR_Accepted resets to false, and the GDPR banner is shown again even though the user had previously accepted the terms. Why isn't localStorage persisting the data when the user leaves?

Here is my Context API code where I handle the GDPR_Accepted state:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_GDPR: {
            return {
                ...state,
                GDPR: state.GDPR === false ? true : false
            }
        }
        default: {
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
    }
}

export const GlobalContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (storageAvailable('localStorage')) {
            localStorage.setItem('GDPR_Accepted', state.GDPR)
          }
          else {
            return 0;
          }
    }, [state])

    return (
        <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
            <GlobalDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                {children}
            </GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>
        </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I also have this function I took from MDN docs that first checks is local storage is available:

```
// Checks if localStorage is available in the user's browser
   function storageAvailable(type) {
    var storage;
    try {
        storage = window[type];
        var x = '__storage_test__';
        storage.setItem(x, x);
        storage.removeItem(x);
        return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
        return e instanceof DOMException && (
            // everything except Firefox
            e.code === 22 ||
            // Firefox
            e.code === 1014 ||
            // test name field too, because code might not be present
            // everything except Firefox
            e.name === 'QuotaExceededError' ||
            // Firefox
            e.name === 'NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED') &&
            // acknowledge QuotaExceededError only if there's something already stored
            (storage && storage.length !== 0);
        }
    }
```

In my frontend I have a component that displays the actual GDPR banner that appears, inside this component I toggle the GDPR_Accepted state being stored in localStorage with this:

```
 <Button className={styles.acceptButton} onClick={async () => {
        dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_GDPR" })
 }}>Accept All Cookies</Button>
```

Then, in my Layout component, I use a ternary to decide if the GDPR banner should be displayed or not. I access the state from the Context API, `const state = useContext(GlobalStateContext);` and then use the ternary:

```
{
   state.GDPR === false ?                    
    <GDPR />
   : null
}
```

All of this works, but I have the issue with persisting the state when the user leaves and comes back. Some possible issues that have crossed my mind:

- Gatsby uses server side rendering, and a lot of Javascript objects built into the language (like `window` or even `localStorage`) throw an error when Gatsby builds due to SSR. I'm not having this issue when I use `localStorage`, which is strange.
- `localStorage` is supposed to only store **strings**, but I can't get my GDPR banner to work when I store **strings** in `localStorage`. I can only get this to work if I use a **boolean**. For some reason **booleans** work but **strings** don't.
- I'm using **context** and it's state to decide whether the banner is shown, should I be checking `localStorage` directly? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `useEffect` hook in the definition of GlobalContextProvider definition is resetting the value of the localStorage key. This function will run (at least) each time the component is mounted (i.e. each page load). There's no need to initialize the localStorage key on each page load. The only place you call `setItem` should be in your button's `onClick`.